# JSON Path Extractor - missing DummySampler

Tags: json, testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a problem with jMeter and JSON Path Extractor.
I downloaded zip file for this plugin and copy content to ext file as it is written on the page. Then I also downloaded jmeter-plugins-manager-0.10.jar and copy it into ext folder.

Next step - downloaded a sample:

https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/JSONPathExtractorExample.jmx

When i try to import it i'm getting exception:

> missing
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.conversionException:kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler:kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler

### EDITED:

I love samples and documentation for libraries. There is no information about install additional jars... just download:

> https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-dummy

And show must go on

Comment: Dummy Sampler Plugin is missing. Install the Dummy sampler plugins via Plugin Manager

Answer (score 1):

Since JMeter 3.0 you don't need any plugin for JSON.
There is natively a new one :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor

Regarding the issue maybe you can report the problem to jmeter-plugins project

Comment: I resolved this problem with jmeter-plugins, but still i think the better solution is that i proposed in post below

Comment: I don"t share your opinion :-) Why script with JSR223 and very slow javascript while feature natively exists with JSON Post Processor ?

Answer (score 0):

i used JSR223 Sampler where i parse input json and validate it's values in pure JavaScript. It seems more simple.

Here is and example code:

```
var json = JSON.parse(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString());

//get your jmeter context
var ctx = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext()
var vars = ctx.getVariables();

if(json[0].itemId != 1){
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(json);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
} else {
    //and put data to this context, that you can use it in other components.
    vars.put('validationJsonRequest', true);
}
```

To see added data just use Debug Sampler or Debug post processor (which you can investigate in View Result Tree)